# auto-index the dataset list from selected packages in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to index all the datasets from a selection of packages. The following code, bugs but i don't see why:

```
pn<-c("robust","rrcov","robustbase")
for(j in 1:length(pn)){
    a1<-length(data(package=pn[j])$results[,3])
    for(i in 1:a1){
        data(cat(as.vector(data(package=pn[j])$results[i,3]),"\n"),package=as.character(pn[j]))
        print(dim(cat(as.vector(data(package=pn[j])$results[i,3]),"\n")))
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

what i would like it, essentially is to load the dataset, in order, say, to check the size of it (for example, for the pair wood, robustbase)

```
data(wood,package="robustbase")
dim(wood)
>20 6
```

would load "wood" from robustbase, but for j=3,i=38 the function above returns:

```
Warning message:
In data(cat(as.vector(data(package = pn[j])$results[i, 3]), "\n"),  :
  data set ‘cat(as.vector(data(package = pn[j])$results[i, 3]), "\n")’ not found
```

Comment: Maybe add an example of the output you want the loop to return, in the desired format.  dim seems to return NULL for me, but I am not sure what it should be returning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the same set of packages as Mark

```
pn<-c("ggplot2","plyr","reshape")

for (package in pn) {
    datasets <- data(package=package)$results[,"Item"]
    for (d in datasets) {
        cat(package, "\t", d, "\t")
        print(dim(eval(parse(text=paste(package,"::",d,sep="")))))
    }
}
```

I iterate a little differently, looping over the vectors directly (which saves re-indexing into the vector). However, I am using `eval(parse(text=...))` which is often an indication that this isn't the best approach (see `fortune(106)`):

> If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question.
>         -- Thomas Lumley
>            R-help (February 2005)

The results of this loop are:

```
ggplot2      diamonds   [1] 53940    10
ggplot2      economics  [1] 478   6
ggplot2      midwest    [1] 437  28
ggplot2      movies     [1] 58788    24
ggplot2      mpg    [1] 234  11
ggplot2      msleep     [1] 83 11
ggplot2      presidential   [1] 10  4
ggplot2      seals  [1] 1155    4
plyr     baseball   [1] 21699    22
plyr     ozone  [1] 24 24 72
reshape      french_fries   [1] 696   9
reshape      smiths     [1] 2 5
reshape      tips   [1] 244   7
```

Comment: thanks! Works like a charm. For most user, efficiency is not going to be an issue, this is essentially a run once and store the results kind of deal :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the best that I can do tonight.  I used a different set of packages.

```
pn<-c("ggplot2","plyr","reshape")
for(j in 1:length(pn)){
    a1<-length(data(package=pn[j])$results[,3])
    for(i in 1:a1){
    cat( data(package=pn[j])$results[i,3] , package=as.character(pn[j]), "\n" )
    }
}
```

The output I got is here.

```
diamonds ggplot2 
economics ggplot2 
midwest ggplot2 
movies ggplot2 
mpg ggplot2 
msleep ggplot2 
presidential ggplot2 
seals ggplot2 
baseball plyr 
ozone plyr 
french_fries reshape 
smiths reshape 
tips reshape
```

EDIT

I believe the reason `dim` returned `NULL` in your code is because the data sets were not actually available because the libraries had not been opened.  Your code and mine, I believe, is simply reading a text file that contains the names of data sets that are in a library.

You can load multiple libraries using:

```
lapply(pn, require, character.only=T)
```

However, I have not yet figured out how to access data sets recursively after the libraries have been loaded.

Comment: Okay.  I will try to add the size of the data sets later if nobody posts a solution in the next 20 hours or so.

Answer (score 1):

I get much better results with this code: the code posted by Mark Miller works fine 
on the three examples we used for illustration, but somehow fails to list all datasets....

```
rm(list=ls())
library("session")
#AAA002<-data(package=.packages(all.available=TRUE))$results[,3]
AAA001<-unique(data(package=.packages(all.available=TRUE))$results[,1])

AAA000<-rep(NA,4)
AAA005<-AAA004<-NA
for(AAA003 in AAA001){#AAA003<-AAA001[3]
    script<-paste("library(",AAA003,")",sep="") 
    printed(script)
    AAA002<-data(package=AAA003) 
    data(list=AAA002$results[,3]) 
    AAA004<-ls()[-c(1:6)]
    for(AAA005 in AAA004){#j<-AAA004[11]
        script<-paste("dim(",AAA005,")",sep="")
        result<-strsplit(printed(script)," ")
        result<-as.numeric(c(result[[1]][2],result[[1]][length(result[[1]])]))
        AAA000<-rbind(AAA000,c(AAA003,AAA005,result))
    }
    rm(list=ls()[-c(1:6)])
}
a1<-na.omit(AAA000)
a2<-data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow(a1),ncol(a1)))
a2[,1:2]<-a1[,1:2]
a2[,3:4]<-as.numeric(a1[,3:4])
```